# Prove that $D^n(f\cdot g)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} D^{n-k} f(x) \cdot D^kg(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have to prove that
$$
D^n(f\cdot g)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} D^{n-k} f(x) \cdot D^kg(x)
$$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and f and g is assumed to be differentiable in an interval I and where $D^mh$ is the m'th derivative of the function h. I really have no idea where to start. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 3):

To add more detail to supplement the other answer:

It is good to try to prove this by induction. Look at the base case, $n=0$, and see if you can figure out what the sum on the right simplifies to and why it is true in that case. Now, **assume** that for some $n$ we have
$$D^n(f\cdot g)(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} D^{n-k} f(x) \cdot D^kg(x).$$
Now,
$$D^{n+1}(f\cdot g)(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} D\left(D^{n-k} f(x) \cdot D^kg(x)\right).$$

Each term, $D\left(D^{n-k} f(x) \cdot D^kg(x)\right)$, is simply the derivative of a product, so you can expand it using the product rule. Can you see how the sum you get from this can be manipulated to get what you want? Remember Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to solve it recursively.

And the basic form is compound derivative:

$$D(f \cdot g) = Df \cdot g + f \cdot Dg.$$

Then try it with the induction.

Comment: Hi, thanks. So the above expression I wrote is just the product rule used n-times? Is this understood correctly? And therefore the first induction step would be to check for n = 1 in the expression, assume OK for n and then prove for n+1? Furthermore what does it mean to solve it recursively? I have heard recursively before but I am not sure what it means. Do you mind explaining? Thanks.

Comment: The definition of $D^n$ is a recursive definition, it uses the $D^{n-1}$.  $D^n(f) = D(D^{n-1}(f)) D$. So try the proof from the conclusion for $n-1$ to the conclusion for $n$ can be easier since you just get something for "nothing".